# Failed to import multiprocessing Queue object in python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I was using multiprocessing library in python. I have python 3.6. Whenever i  try to create the multiprocessing. Queue() object i get an error.

My code looks like:

```
import multiprocessing

def square(arr,q):
    for i in arr:
        q.put(i*i)


arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
q=multiprocessing.Queue()
p1=multiprocessing.Process(target=square,args=(arr,q,))

p1.start()
p1.join()

result=[]

while q.empty() is False:
    result.append(q.get())

print(result)
```

and error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "qu.py", line 9, in <module>
    q=multiprocessing.Queue()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/context.py", line 101, in Queue
    from .queues import Queue
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 20, in <module>
    from queue import Empty, Full
  File "/home/vivek/Desktop/code/par/queue.py", line 11, in <module>
    q=Queue()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/context.py", line 101, in Queue
    from .queues import Queue
ImportError: cannot import name 'Queue'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the import chain listed in the error traceback, Python is trying to import the `Queue` definition from:

```
/home/vivek/Desktop/code/par/queue.py
```

This indicates you have somehow broken Python import logic as usually it prioritizes modules in `/lib` `/usr/lib` folders. This usually happens if you set your custom `PYTHONPATH` environment variable or if you mess with module variables such as `sys.path`.

Quick fix is to rename your file from `queue.py` to something else.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if so. This helps people having similar problems.